# Venv doesn't know where Python.h is

Tags: python, header-files, python-venv

I'v setup venv on my Windows machine and whenever I try to run a python script that imports a package that needs Python.h, it comes with an error that says it can't find the Python.h file. I know where Python.h is located on my machine (AppData/local/Python/Python3.8/Include) but how do I tell venv to look for it in that directory?

Comment: How did you create your venv? Did you activate it? Please provide more details.

Comment: What package are you importing? You might want to just pivot to using conda/anaconda which has a much more comprehensive set of pre-compiled packages. Your package probably doesn't have pre-compiled binaries for windows, so you are going to have to provide all the hints to where the c++ compiler is, where the header files are, etc.

Comment: Thanks for asking. I created venv using the standard command
`python -m venv`
I activated it by running 
`/Scripts/Activate.ps1`

Comment: I'm trying to import [Jittor](https://github.com/Jittor/Jittor).
It does have a windows install instruction which I followed till the end but I guess it wasn't precompiled.
I'll try and find the complier and see if I can tell it where the header files are.